# How to filter rows in listview based on matching value with textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listview

I am making billing software. Here if we press any key in datagridview1 third column listview2 populate from datatable dt9. After that if we type in textbox11 then textchangevent will filter datatable according to datatable value matching with textbox11.text.
Here is my code.

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyPress
    Dim c2 As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.CurrentCell

    If c2.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
        If (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) Then Return
        If Trim(DataGridView1.Rows(c2.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value).Length = 0 AndAlso DataGridView1.Rows(c2.RowIndex).Cells(6).ReadOnly = True Then
            MsgBox("Please Enter the Item Name.")
        End If
    End If


    If c2.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
        If (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) Then Return
        TextBox12.Text = Integer.Parse(c2.RowIndex)

        conn9.Open()
        Dim strSQL9 As String
        Dim cmd9 As SqlCommand
        Dim da9 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim df As New DataTable
        dt9.Clear()
        strSQL9 = "Select Col_Barcode as Barcode,Col_Pro_Name as Item,Col_Pack_Size as [Pack Size],Col_Brand as Brand,Col_Curr_Stock as Stock,Col_Base_Rate as DPL,Col_A_Rate as [Rate A],Col_B_Rate as [Rate B],Col_C_Rate as [Rate C],Col_D_Rate as [Rate D] From Tab_Item_M where Col_Pro_Name IS NOT NULL Order by Col_Pro_Name ASC"
        cmd9 = New SqlCommand(strSQL9, conn9)
        cmd9.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        da9.SelectCommand = cmd9
        da9.Fill(dt9)
        conn9.Close()
        Panel7.Visible = True
        Panel7.Size = New Size(1007, 375)
        TextBox11.Text = e.KeyChar
        TextBox11.Focus()
        TextBox11.Select(TextBox11.Text.Length, 0)
    End If
    e.Handled = True
End Sub



Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Interval = 250
    Timer1.Stop()
    Dim df As DataTable = dt9.Clone
    df.Clear()
    Dim Rows As DataRow() = dt9.[Select]("Item like '%" & TextBox11.Text & "%'")

    For Each row As DataRow In Rows
        df.ImportRow(row)
    Next

    With ListView2
        .View = View.Details
        .GridLines = True
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Items.Clear()
    End With

    For Each col As DataColumn In df.Columns
        ListView2.Columns.Add(col.ToString)
    Next

    For Each row As DataRow In df.Rows
        Dim lst1 As ListViewItem = ListView2.Items.Add(If(row(0) IsNot Nothing, row(0).ToString, String.Empty))

        For i As Integer = 1 To df.Columns.Count - 1
            lst1.SubItems.Add(If(row(i) IsNot Nothing, row(i).ToString, String.Empty))
        Next
    Next
    ListView2.Columns.Item(0).Width = 70
    ListView2.Columns.Item(1).Width = 300
    ListView2.Columns.Item(2).Width = 90
    ListView2.Columns.Item(3).Width = 100
    ListView2.Columns.Item(5).Width = 70
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox11_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox11.TextChanged
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

The problem is sometime it not work but sometime works.
Is my codes are correct? I am new in coding. Please give me your suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use a `ListView` in the first place. Bind the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and bind that to a `DataGridView`. You can then filter by setting the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`.

Comment: Thank You sir I get my solution. Also learn a new topic filter property of binding source.